# Using GET for delete in REST

Tags: java, rest, web-services, get

what is the technical drawback of deleting a row on a GET method call in REST i know that it is not a standard way of doing but will there be having any issues ?

Answer (score 0):

The technical drawback is that indexers (think Google) come along and GET all of the links that they can find, just to see what's there.  General purpose components that see a link to your thing might do a GET on it as a way of pre-caching the results in case the client wants them.

Fielding, [writing in 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)

> HTTP does not attempt to require the results of a GET to be safe.  What
> it does is require that the semantics of the operation be safe, and
> therefore it is a fault of the implementation, not the interface
> or the user of that interface, if anything happens as a result that
> causes loss of property (money, BTW, is considered property for the
> sake of this definition)